# Color code in project not executing properly

Tags: ios, swift, xcode6

Hey fellow iOs programmers. I have run into a dilemma trying to complete a tutorial I found online. The problem is that the app is suppose to display a gradient affect to the app but whenever I run the simulator, the piece of code that is suppose to add that gradient affect is not executing. Xcode isn't giving me any errors but the cells are the default white in the simulator. I am a beginner so it might be something easy to fix or see the problem. Any help would be appreciated!

```
 import UIKit

    class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource,       UITableViewDelegate {


@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

 var toDoItems = [ToDoItem]()

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    tableView.dataSource = self
    tableView.delegate = self
    tableView.registerClass(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier:   "cell")
    tableView.separatorStyle = .None
    tableView.rowHeight = 50.0;


    if toDoItems.count > 0 {
        return
    }

    toDoItems.append(ToDoItem(text: "Do homework"))
    toDoItems.append(ToDoItem(text: "Feed the cat"))
    toDoItems.append(ToDoItem(text: "Take out the garbage"))
    toDoItems.append(ToDoItem(text: "Learn Swift"))
    toDoItems.append(ToDoItem(text: "Get a haircut"))
    toDoItems.append(ToDoItem(text: "Fix the laptop"))
    toDoItems.append(ToDoItem(text: "Take a shower"))
    toDoItems.append(ToDoItem(text: "Work out"))

}
  // Tabel view data source

  func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) ->
 Int {
return 1
 }


func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) ->       Int {

return toDoItems.count

}
 func tableView(tableView: UITableView,
 cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell",
        forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell
    let item = toDoItems[indexPath.row]
    cell.textLabel?.text = item.text
    return cell

}
```

**// Color of cells**
 ** Here is the piece of code that is not working!**

```
     func colorForIndex(index: Int) -> UIColor {
        let itemCount = toDoItems.count - 1
        let val = (CGFloat(index) / CGFloat(itemCount)) * 0.6
        return UIColor(red: 1.0, green: val, blue: 0.0, alpha: 1.0)
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, willDisplayCell cell: UITableViewCell,
        forRowatIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
            cell.backgroundColor = colorForIndex(indexPath.row)


    }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You have a typo in your function name.  It should be `forRowAtIndexPath` (with a capital A in At):

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, willDisplayCell cell: UITableViewCell,
    forRowatIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
         ^^^ typo here
        cell.backgroundColor = colorForIndex(indexPath.row)
}
```